# I want to update the data on this d3.js bar chart by clicking a button. (onclick)

Tags: javascript, svg, charts, d3.js

How would I go about telling D3 to push a new chart with new random data by clicking the button I created? right now I get new data by refreshing the page but I want to be able to push a new chart without having the page reload.

```
</script>
    var w = 500;
    var h = 500;
    var barPadding = 1;

    var dataset = [ ];

    for (var i = 0; i < 14; i++) {var newNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 70);
    dataset.push(newNumber);}



    var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);

    var widthScale = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d,i) {return d;})])
                    .range([0,w]);

        svg.selectAll("rect")
            .data(dataset)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("x", 3)
            .attr("y", function (d,i) {return i* 36;}) 
            .attr("width", widthScale)
            .transition()
            .duration(1000)
            .attr("height", h / dataset.length - barPadding)
            .attr("fill", function(d) {return "rgb(0, 0, " + (d * 10) + ")";});

        svg.selectAll("text")
            .data(dataset)
            .enter()
            .append("text")
            .text(function(d) {return d;})
            .attr("x", function(d) {return widthScale(d) -17;})
            .attr("y", function(d,i) {return (i * 36) + 23 ;})
            .attr("fill", "white")
            .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle");
```

Comment: Have you seen [this tutorial](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/02/update-d3js-data-dynamically-button.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include specify the `.update()` and `.exit()` of the selection. Ideally you should change your code so it only called `.data(dataset)` once.

```
var g = svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(dataset);
```

And then you can define what to do on `.enter()` `.update()` and `.exit()`. Your `.enter()`s would start `g.enter().append('rect')` and `g.enter().append('text')` respectively. Whilst you will need to work on the `.update()` the exit can be as simple as removing the object.

```
g.exit()
    .remove();
```

For most data the identity of each datum is the index value. If that is not the case then you will need to make sure you provide an accessors

```
    .data(data, function(d) { return d.name; })
```

I would recommend [this tutorial on bar charts](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/bar-2.html) which should get you up to speed. If it's too advance then try [part 1](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/bar-1.html) to start with.  You could even remove the requirement for the user to click a button to update.

Comment: I will be reading the links you posted along with some info on w3schools. They are still a bit confusing to me since I'm starting to learn programming from absolute zero. Thanks

Comment: Those tutorial and the answer assume a reasonable level of understanding of JavaScript If you want to get the most of D3 then I recommend a primer in JavaScript first. Typical primer texts for languages are "Sams teach yourself JavaScript in 21 days" and others. Check your local library holdings, search the site for an existing question on learning JS and maybe ask in the [Stack Overflow Javacript Chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript) for a recommendation.